# How to get time difference during mobile shaking in android?

Tags: android

My question is how to get time duration between shaking the mobile by using accelerometer in android. My default threshold value is 800, and speed calculation formula is:

```
speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;
```

Here I want to get time duration between first shake and next shake. If the duration is more than 10 sec means alert have to generate.

I don't know how to calculate time intervals in sensor concepts. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use  `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the time for the first shake and save it to some variable say `preTime` and when the user shakes again then you can get time difference simply subtracting like this   `diffTime =  System.currentTimeMillis() - preTime`

and now if the value of `diffeTime/(1000 *10) > 10` then do your rest of calculation

Answer (score 0):

to check your phone rotation you can use accelerometer sensor,

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

But you need check for full rotation using this sensor and increment the value of rotation

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static final int FORCE_THRESHOLD = 800;
    private static final int TIME_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SHAKE_TIMEOUT = 500;
    private static final int SHAKE_DURATION = 1000;
    private static final int SHAKE_COUNT = 3;
    private float mLastX=-1.0f, mLastY=-1.0f, mLastZ=-1.0f;
    private long mLastTime;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mShakeCount = 0;
    private long mLastShake;
    private long mLastForce;



    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                                if(event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) return;

    Log.v("sensor","sensor change is verifying");
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((now - mLastForce) > SHAKE_TIMEOUT) {
        mShakeCount = 0;
    }

    if ((now - mLastTime) > TIME_THRESHOLD) {
      long diff = now - mLastTime;
      float speed = Math.abs(event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X] + event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y] + event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z] - mLastX - mLastY - mLastZ) / diff * 10000;
      if (speed > FORCE_THRESHOLD) {
        if ((++mShakeCount >= SHAKE_COUNT) && (now - mLastShake > SHAKE_DURATION)) 
        {
           mLastShake = now;
           mShakeCount = 0;
            //call the reaction you want to have happen
            onShake();
         }
         mLastForce = now;
       }
         mLastTime = now;
         mLastX = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
         mLastY = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
         mLastZ = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];
      }
  }
```